# Azure DevOps: How to merge two code coverage reports for different tests (.net core, angular)

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, code-coverage, azure-pipelines, karma-coverage

We have two different types of tests in pipeline: unit(.net core) and frontend (angular/karma). Each of them can publish code coverage report via to "PublishCodeCoverageResults@1", but only one front or back. It depends on which test runs last. I think the last coverage owerwrites previous. However we need both code coverage publish.

Is there way to merge 2 coverage report and then publish them in one Code Coverage tab or add the second tab?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there way to merge 2 coverage report and then publish them in one Code Coverage tab or add the second tab?

AFAIK, ReportGenerator can merge multiple coverage files into one, e.g. merge several Cobertura XML files into just one Cobertura XML file:

Check the document [ReportGenerator](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator) for some more details.

You can do the following steps in the Azure devops:

> - Install the ReportGenerator extension:    https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Palmmedia.reportgenerator
> - Configure the ReportGenerator task to produce HTML and Cobertura    (this is the default)
> - Configure the Publish code coverage results task and point it to the    HTML files directory and the merged Cobertura file generated by
>     ReportGenerator
>
> Currently the Publish code coverage results task regenerates the HTML
>   report. To avoid that, you have to create a new environment variable:
>   disable.coverage.autogenerate: 'true'

Check [this thread](https://github.com/tonerdo/coverlet/issues/474#issuecomment-504435186) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you generate Angular and .Net Core summary files and show them in AzureDevops?